# How to read text file and insert the extracted info into database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, text

I have a text file containing multiple sets of following info:

```
-----------------------------------
TXN NO        : 30
DATE & TIME   : 30/09/16 16:48:28
TXN TYPE      : CASH WITHDRAWAL
CARD NO       : 436444XXXXXX6086
TRANS AMOUNT  : 3,000.00
COUNTERS      : 5 -   0 , 6 -   0 , 7 -   0 , 8 -   0 
AUTH CODE     : 606662
TRACE NO/ID   : 606662
RESP CODE     : 00
-----------------------------------
```

Now I needed to insert each corresponding key/value pair into the database.

This is what I tried:

```
$target_file = 'my_file.txt';
$lines = file($target_file);//file in to an array

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $var = explode(':', $line, 2);
    $arr[$var[0]] = $var[1];
}
//finally inserted $arr to data table
```

This failed to insert the key/value pairs.

Comment: where's the db code? you tagged as "mysql". Your "tried" code might have failed due to a possible sql injection.

Comment: I've not given there my db code. Used like below line to insert each set of $arr to table.

$db_object->query_insert('tbl_name', $arr);

// Obviously; connection exists before this.

Comment: check for errors then, or wait for someone who has already used the same method.

Comment: show your code  .. for db .. even if it is wrong

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need code that demonstrates the problem, not the beginning of code. We help you fix what you wrote but if you don't show us the minimum code that demonstrates it we'll come up with solutions that are not related to what you wrote, which doesn't help you and wastes our time.

Comment: It can probably be done with essentially zero code, if you use `LOAD DATA INFILE to do the reading, parsing, and inserting for you -- all in one step.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have the extra colon (:) in date and time. You have to remove that. Your problem might be in the sql as well.

```
<?php

$lines = file('test.txt');//file in to an array
$var = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $var[] = array_map('trim', explode(':', $line, 2));   
}

for($x=0; $x<count($var); $x++){
    foreach($var[$x] as $k){
        echo $k.'<br>';//Insert into database
    }
}

?>
```

Hope this may help.